# XML Feeds & PHP - Limit the number of items

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I am pulling through the BBC News XML Feed. But what I want to do is limit it to say 8 or 10 items of the feed.

How can I achieve this?

My code is :

```
<?php

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->load('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml');
  $arrFeeds = array();
  foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $itemRSS = array ( 
      'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
      'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
      'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
      'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue
      );
?>

<h2><a href="<?php echo $itemRSS['link'] ;?>"><?php echo $itemRSS['title']; ?></a></h2>
<?php  } ?>
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a counter variable, increment by one with each iteration and check if the counter is reached at the upper limit and then exit from loop.

```
$cnt=0;
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    if($cnt == 8 ) {
       break;
     }    
    $itemRSS = array ( 
      'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
      'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
      'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
      'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue
      );
      $cnt++;
?>    
<h2><a href="<?php echo $itemRSS['link'] ;?>"><?php echo $itemRSS['title']; ?></a></h2>
<?php 
} ?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that get 9 because you are starting at 0 and incrementing at the bottom?

Comment: @RyanMatthews: Yes, true. I just shown an example how it can be done.

Comment: @ShaktiSingh thanks for that, Works a treat. I was looking at a count var, just had it in the wrong place.. Perfect answer, Thanks.

Comment: @Positive Is it possible to fetch the items randomly between the xml? Suppose, i would like to fetch the items 11 to 20 in the xml. For this, do i need to parse the entire xml, before slicing the result and displaying it?

Answer (score 7):

Using XPath you can easily retrieve a subset of the RSS feed.

```
$itemCount = 10;
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml');
$items = $xml->xpath(sprintf('/rss/channel/item[position() <= %d]', $itemCount));
foreach ($items as $i) {
    $itemRSS = array ( 
        'title' => (string)$i->title,
        'desc' => (string)$i->description,
        'link' => (string)$i->link,
        'date' => (string)$i->pubDate
    );
}
```

You be a little more lightweight by exchanging the `DOM` object by a `SimpleXML` object - and XPath is much easier to use with `SimpleXML` (that's why I used it in this example). The same can be achieved with `DOM` like that:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$items = $xpath->query(sprintf('/rss/channel/item[position() <= %d]', $itemCount));
foreach ($items as $i) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I like this method and will no doubt use it in the future. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you do it with `SimpleXml`, you can also use `array_slice`:

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml');
$items = $rss->xpath('/rss/channel/item');
$startAtItem = 0;
$numberOfItems = 9;
$firstTenItems = array_slice($items, $startAtItem, $numberOfItems);
```

Or with a `LimitIterator`:

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml');
$items = $rss->xpath('/rss/channel/item');
$startAtItem = 0;
$numberOfItems = 9;
$firstTenItems = new LimitIterator(
    new ArrayIterator($items), $startAtItem, $numberOfItems
);
foreach ($firstTenItems as $item) { …
```

More elegant is the XPath `position()` solution presented elsewhere on this site though.